# how to compare two pyspark dataframe with multiple values in first dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a scenario where I have to do comparison between two dataframes. But the values in on the data frame is in such a way that one to one mapping is not possible.

First data frame(df1) has below sample row values.

```
canada
canada
canada.Italy.Rome
canada.USA.Brazil
USA.Brazil
canada.Rome
```

Note: The vertical sequence is very random. i.e.

```
- there are possibilities that for multiple rows there could be only single value row.
- there are possibilities that few rows could have two values and so on.
```

Second data frame(df2) will have only single value per row.

```
canada
USA
Italy
Rome
```

The comparison requirement is as below

```
- if there is single value in df1 and when compared with df2, and if the value matches the column then xyz_lst should be updated with df1 value. i.e. if df1 and df2 has canada then its a match. otherwise the xyz_lst should be updated as NULL.

- If a row in DF1 has two values separated by a dot, then the comparison will start from the left hand side value of the dot and compared with df2. If "canada" matches then no further comarison is required, and xyz_lst should be updated with "canada". Should the left hand side value in df1 is not canada, the right hand side of the dot in df1 is compared with df2. If match, then update with df1 value or NULL

- same logic as explained above for the row having 3 values in single row. i.e. canada.USA.Rome
```

below is the code snippet that I am trying to work on

```
arrayCol = ArrayType(StringType(),False)

def tryu(li):
    if li.count(".") > 0:
        if li.count(".") == 1:
            a = li.split('.')
        else:
            a = li.split('.')
    else:
        a = [li]
    return a
spark.udf.register("squaredWithPython", tryu, arrayCol)
modify_net_premium_increment_settlmnt_df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")

sql_df = spark.sql("select test.*, squaredWithPython(xyz) as xyz_lst from test")

first_df = sql_df.filter(size(col("FILList_lst")) == 1)
sec_df = sql_df.filter(size(col("FILList_lst")) == 2)
third_df = sql_df.filter(size(col("FILList_lst")) > 2)
```

I am stuck, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Question is vague. A sample of the expected output would make it clear. This is how I have understood it though. Let me know if this works for you.

Basically, split the names by `.` in `df1` and eliminate any name that is not `canada`. Store this in a new column.

Data

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("canada",1),
                                  ("Rome.Italy.CANADA",2),
                                  ("canada.Italy.Rome",3),
                                  ("canaDA.usa",4),
                                  ("UK.canada",5),
                                  ("USA.Brazil",6)], 
                            ('country_df1', 'id'))

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("canada",1),
                                  ("USA",2),
                                  ("Italy",3),
                                  ("Rome",4)], 
                            ('country_df2', 'id2'))
```

code

```
df1 =df1.withColumn('check', array_intersect(split(lower(col('country_df1')),'\.'),array(lit('canada')))[0])
df1.join(df2.select('country_df2'),how='left', on=df1.check==df2.country_df2).show()
```

output

```
+-----------------+---+------+-----------+
|      country_df1| id| check|country_df2|
+-----------------+---+------+-----------+
|       USA.Brazil|  6|  null|       null|
|           canada|  1|canada|     canada|
|Rome.Italy.CANADA|  2|canada|     canada|
|canada.Italy.Rome|  3|canada|     canada|
|       canaDA.usa|  4|canada|     canada|
|        UK.canada|  5|canada|     canada|
+-----------------+---+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Your output seems to be exactly what it should be. Let me try it on my data. Will keep posted

Comment: Accept the answer then and upvote. Doesn't surprise me because that's what your logic looked like